# error in setadded statement

Tags: vb.net

Below code  dr.SetAdded() statement gives error like this:

"setadded and setmodified can only be called on data rows with unchanged datarowstate"
What to do Now?

```
      dBindSet.AcceptChanges()


         For Each dt As DataTable In dBindSet.Tables

   BindingContext(dt).EndCurrentEdit()

          For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows

                    dr.SetAdded()

                    dr.Item("CREATEDON") = strServerDate
                    dr.Item("CREATEDBY") = iUserID

                 Next
            Next
```

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do here. First, you call AcceptChanges, then call EndCurrentEdit (on which row?) then you try to set the rowstate to Added for every row in the current datatable (as every row should be inserted as new in the database) Probably if you explain what are your intentions we could answer with a different approach.

Comment: i don't want to add any new row in datatable but i just want to just check that if the datatable has any row then update that datable column name of "CREATEDON","CREATEDBY" of exist row.

Comment: Then remove the `dr.SetAdded()`. In your case is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Method `SetAdded` changes the `RowState`  to Added. In OP, you are updating the fields so you don't have to call this method.

In case if you want to call this method then check the `RowState`.

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
   If dr.RowState=DataRowstate.Unchanged Then
      dr.SetAdded()
   End If
   dr.Item("CREATEDON") = strServerDate
   dr.Item("CREATEDBY") = iUserID
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to set the "CREATEDON" and "CREATEDBY" fields of the datatables in every row that has been changed or inserted in your tables. If this is the case you should not call `AcceptChanges` because this will reset the `RowState` property of every DataRow to `Unchanged` and you will not be able to process the rows changed (and the database update will fail)

```
' Don't call this, you will loose the RowState info....
'dBindSet.AcceptChanges()
For Each dt As DataTable In dBindSet.Tables
    ' Not really needed here. It serves to update the UI. 
    'BindingContext(dt).EndCurrentEdit()
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        if(dr.RowState = DataRowState.Added OrElse dr.RowState = DataRowState.Modified then            
            dr.Item("CREATEDON") = strServerDate
            dr.Item("CREATEDBY") = iUserID
        end if
    Next
Next
```